# Unable to upload Phat Contract build using cargo-contract-2.1.0

Tags: ink, smart-contract, test-network, phala

I was unable to add contract into https://phat.phala.network/contracts/add.

At the

The contract was built using:
cargo-contract version : cargo-contract-contract 2.1.0-unknown-aarch64-apple-darwin

the contract.json's snippet

```
"source": {
"hash": "0x2bb725e2c31290294d3cb9f5eb1c52347cfe770a74c5f1a06d69aeb4f7b4bbbc",
"language": "ink! 4.0.1",
"compiler": "rustc 1.70.0-nightly",
"build_info": {
  "build_mode": "Debug",
  "cargo_contract_version": "2.1.0",
  "rust_toolchain": "nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin",
  "wasm_opt_settings": {
    "keep_debug_symbols": false,
    "optimization_passes": "Z"
  }
}
```

[image: Error when uploading the contract]

Comment: You may want to open an issue on there Github.

Comment: @Bruno thanks ,will ask this in discord before creating an issue in appropriate Phala Repo

Answer (score 3):

<del>We haven't enabled support for ink 4 in production or on our testnet yet. As it's a major version update, if you want to experiment with ink 4, you'll need to deploy your own testnet.</del>

The Phat Contracts UI has been updated to support Ink v4 metadata. We are still in the process of upgrading to Ink 4, so if you encounter any issues, please contact us.

Comment: Any plans to? Of so where should people track this? Perhaps an issue?

Comment: Yes, we have a few issues for tracking:
- Phat UI: https://github.com/Phala-Network/phat-contract-ui/pull/40
- Phat Hello Contract: https://github.com/Phala-Network/phat-hello/pull/1
- We will make an announcement a week before upgrading out testnet to ensure deployed contracts are prepared for the migration.

Comment: @DanShields You can track the announcement in our Discord. For the support on UI, as I updated above, it does right now.